# NumberFormatException while trying to print reverse of 32 bit binary number

Tags: java, binary, decimal, numberformatexception

I am trying to print reverse of a 32 bit binary number in decimal format:
Example:

> x = 3,
>             00000000000000000000000000000011 
>   =>        11000000000000000000000000000000
>
> return 3221225472

I am getting a number format exception, can anyone please help me whats wrong in my code? I appreciate your help.

```
public class ReverseBinary {

    public long reverse(long a) {

        String s1 = String.format("%32s", Long.toBinaryString(a)).replace(' ', '0');
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(s1);
        String s = sb.reverse().toString();

        long c = Integer.parseInt(s, 2);

        return c;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        ReverseBinary rb = new ReverseBinary();

        long ans = rb.reverse(3);

        System.out.println(ans);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your variable `c` might be a long variable, but the value delivered by  `Integer.parseInt(s,2)` is still an integer. This call tries to parse an integer value which causes problems, because the value is obviously out of the integer range.

Simply replace `Integer.parseInt(s,2)` by `Long.parseLong(s, 2)`.

Answer (score 1):

It should be

```
long c= Long.parseLong(s,2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you want the signed integer that corresponds to the reversed bit pattern: there is a method to just do that.

```
public class Test
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        // 000...001 -> 100...000, interpret as two's complement 32bit int
        int reversed = Integer.reverse(0b0_00000000_00000000_00000000_00000001);
        System.out.println(reversed == Integer.MIN_VALUE); // -> true
    }
}
```